# CakePHP query needs to be sorted by JOIN column

Tags: php, cakephp, join, cakephp-model

I'm working on a CakePHP project that's giving me some issue when it comes to query result order. There are three tables used here: Buildings (all the info on the building), Lists, and ListBuildings (a link table for building and list). I didn't build the application, and can't change the db structure unfortunately. I want `$arrBuildings` to be a list of the buildings in order by `ListBuildings.created` (meaning the moment a building was added to a list), and not by `Building.name` as it appears to be right now.

```
function getList($list_id) {   
// Get buildings in the list
$building_ids = $this->_getBuildingsForList($list_id);
$conditions = array(
        'conditions'=>array('Building.id'=>$building_ids),
        'contain' => array(
                'List'=>array('conditions' => array ('List.id'=>$list_id))));

// Get the list information
$this->Building->List->recursive=-1;
$List=$this->Building->List->read(null,$list_id);

$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Building.id'=>$building_ids),
    'contain' => array(
        'List'=>array('conditions' => array ('List.id'=>$list_id)),
        'Sqft'
    ),
);


$this->Building->myId=$this->getUserId();
$arrBuildings = $this->Building->find('all', $options);
print_r($arrBuildings);
}
```

Since I'm using CakePHP, the model portion of MVC seems to be set up properly. With the code above, `print_r` shows the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[Building] => Array ( 
    [id] => 105 
    [name] => Stark Tower 
    [address] => 123 Main St. 
) 
[Sqft] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 51 
        [list_id] => 113 
        [building_id] => 105 
        [sq_feet] => 2200.000 
    ) 
) 
[List] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 113 
        [title] => Awesome buildings 
        [ListBuilding] => Array ( 
            [id] => 95 
            [list_id] => 113 
            [building_id] => 105 
            [created] => 2012-10-18 09:40:00 ))))
```

**To re-state: How can I order the query (and resulting array) by** `ListBuildings.Created`**?**
I've tried to anonymize the code, and may have messed something out, so let me know if anything doesn't make sense :)
Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: where is your join? I don't see it

Comment: @BarryChapman, CakePHP joins these tables within its Model "hasandbelongstomany" structure. All this "automagical" stuff makes my head spin.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were doing an explicit join in your find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a look at your function again, I think its best to start from scratch here.

Change your model relationships to:

`Building belongsTo ListBuilding`, `ListBuilding hasMany Building`, `List belongsTo ListBuilding`, and finally `ListBuilding hasMany List`.

Rewrite your function

```
    function getList($list_id) {   
    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'ListBuilding.list_id' => $list_id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Sqft'
        ),
        'order' => 'ListBuilding.created',
    );

    $arrBuildings = $this->Building->find('all', $options);
    print_r($arrBuildings);
    }
```

It really doesn't have to be more complicated than that.

Comment: Ahhhh. This is perfect except the application I'm working on is not. haha. Not your problem, but the model relationships were all set up wrong, so changing them breaks everything else. Oh well. Marking this as the answer since it's theoretically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when you have additional data on join tables, it is better to just do some temporary binds on the fly to make it a hasMany and belongsTo to associations. So Building hasMany ListBuild and ListBuild belongsTo List. You could then use the contains to filter down the data you need and also use the order within the contain to give the desired results.